# Как начать изучать SQL?

Tags: sql

Дорогие друзья!

Посоветуйте, как лучше всего начать изучать программную среду баз SQL, если опыт в програмировании уже есть. =) Большое спасибо.

C уважением DataRs.

Answer (score 6):

[Вот тут](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/) можно почитать, [вот тут](http://www.sql-ex.ru/) можно порешать. Для начала - вполне себе ;)

Comment: И не для начала тоже вполне себе. :-)

Comment: хе-хе) я туда 200 ре пожертвований отправлял в свое время ;D

Comment: @Tim Rudnevsky 
Ресурс бесплатный, развивается. Так что не жалейте. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Придумайте какую-нибудь небольшую, для начала, предметную область и формализуйте ее в виде базы данных:

- Список железа или ПО
- Исполнители и альбомы
- Телефонный справочник
- Прайс-лист
- Кулинарная книга
- D&DШный монстрятник/спеллбук

Вобщем, что угодно, с чем вы знакомы, и что будет поддерживать вас интерес. Сделайте оболочку к базе данных на том языке, в котором у вас есть опыт. Заполните базу. Посмотрите, что можно добавить. Постепенно наращивайте функционал. Придумайте какую отчетность и статистику можно собрать по базе (в любом наборе данных можно что-то подсчитать и сгруппировать).

Возможно, легче всего начать разбираться в этом с MS Access. Тут и готовые конструкторы форм и отчетов. Если программируете уверенно, тогда можете писать сразу на своем языке. В таком случае, выбирайте СУБД: MS SQL, MySQL/MariaDB, PostgreSQL. Если боитесь сразу связываться с серверами баз данных, есть файловые СУБД попроще: SQLite, DerbyDB, H2.

Обязательно изучите теорию. Давеча был [открытый стэнфодский курс по базам данных](http://www.db-class.org/course/auth/welcome), если не боитесь английского - очень рекомендую. Или учебник на русском языке от того же профессора: [Системы баз данных. Полный курс](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1351096/). Если сразу освоите теорию реляционных БД, потом будете задавать меньше тривиальных вопросов здесь. )

Успехов.

Answer (score 2):

Я SQL осваивал на основе СУБД  Ms Access из Office 97. Там был полный и понятный хелп на русском, а в их конструкторе SQL понять еще проще!

Answer (score 1):

Так же можно начать с базы SQLite там достаточно простой синтаксис, так же советую для начала прочитать книжку "SQL" Мартина Грабера. Она очень простая и понятная.